# Strapi won't accept my axios.post presumebly because of relations

Tags: reactjs, axios, relationship, strapi, react-query

This returns bad request message (error 400).
my asumption is Strapi is blocking it.. all roles and permissions are granted I doublechecked. populate=* is there. I tried a few other approaches with the field division following strapi docs but to no avail.
this is my code:

```
const { data: response, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["post2"],
    async () => {
      return axios
        .post("http://localhost:1337/api/expences?populate=*", {
          data: {
            month: "march",
            exepenseCatagory: "Bills",
            division: { connect: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 2 }] },
            amount: 3,
            comment: "testing",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        console.log("some message");
      },
      enabled: false,
    }
  );
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Remove `connect` just pass array of [{id..}]